# WordPress MultiSite Link Cloaking/Redirect Solution?

Tags: multisite, links

Is there a method I can use to set and cloak an affiliate link once in WPMS and then all MS blogs will work using that relative link? ie: allWPMSurls.com***/out/productname***

I have several affiliate blogs in a WordPress MultiSite install. They all use the same affiliate links and I'm currently use the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) to cloak them. This works well, but it's fast-becoming too time consuming to update/edit the links in WP Admin for every blog (considering it's the same link for every blog).

All the sites use the same relative link for the affiliate products (/out/product-name) so I'd love to be able to add/edit the links in a single place and for them to work on all the blogs. Navigating into WP Admin > Redirection > Link Setting for *every* blog to change the same link is buckling me.

I tweeted the always-helpful @andrea_r who replied about hard-coding the plugin into mu-plugins. But that is a beyond my skill-set. Has anyone else any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked if my WP Traffic Tools (http://www.wptraffictools.com) does this, and it does not. I thought about changing to the way you wanted, but the potential to bring unwanted overhead onto sub-blogs that do not share common links causes me to stop.

But... if you were to edit the file /wp-traffic-tools/wp-cloakme.php, replacing the following:

{$wpdb->prefix}cloakme_profiles

and

{$table_prefix}cloakme_profiles

with

wpt_cloakme_profiles

Then the the multi-sites would share a table and the urls would work like you're thinking. I bet.

My email is atwell.publishing AT gmail.com; I'm willing to help a little, refund you if we can't get it to work...

Comment: Hey @Adbox. I posting this question on WPQ's, and Denzel gave me a great solution. I might have been over thinking my needs somewhat, as the proposed solution is a different way to attack it, but with a simular result. So I'm I've set up and am trialing Yourls.org's short link system. It means a "prettier" affiliate link, that I can use on any site, and I get the bous of all the stats that come with Yours.org. Here is the discussion on WPQ's: [http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1938](http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1938)